# Why don't SO have a feature to get back the offered bounty to a question if the question receives no answers.?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, bounties

So if i have posted a question and i have awarded some bounty for the question. So if the bounty period expires the bounty points will be reduced from the users account. And the users will never get back the lost points even if the questions does not have an answer. So my question is why SO doesn't have a feature like give back the bounty points to the user if that question receives at least one answer or more than that.

Or what about giving back the bounty points to the user if that question didn't received at least an answer with a minimum number of positive votes..

Otherwise there is no point of losing the points from the reputation.

Comment: They even delete questions with large bounties just to show their power and then you get ban. As I once was unfortunated by a human factor. See hate minuses - I or everybody good couldn't deal with it - force is EVIL. By evil they rule.

Answer (score 21):

You seem to think that bounties are payment for getting answers.

They are not.

They are payment for getting your question **featured**.

Would you ask for your money back on an advertisement you ran in a paper that did not appear to give you the results you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that the reputation spent on bounties is not refunded.

Consider this. The bounty makes the question featured, which in effect is a signal to other users that the question is *more worthy of their attention* than other similar questions. If the question turns out to be just plain bad or so complex that it is unreasonable to expect an answer on SO, then the person who put the bounty **misjudged**, and since reputation is a measure of community trust, it makes sense that they should incur a loss.

Most likely, if it was a really great question but no one could answer, the upvotes on the question will make up for the loss.