# Should awarding a bounty cost you instead of offering one? Can an undeserved bounty be reversed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

It's a little confusing, but it looks like I was docked **50** for *offering* a bounty ona question that was **never** answered.  It also looks like someone awarded **25** to one of the **non**-answers.

UPDATE: Changing this to a "feature request," i.e.,

1. Bounty offered should not be "refunded."  I agree, for the reasons others stated in comments and answers to this.
2. Bounty is offered for an **answer**, not for looking at the question.  Consider any or all of the following:
   **a.** Lengthen the time before any bounty is auto-awarded.
   **b.** Make the number of (upvotes minus downvotes) required for an auto-award higher.
   **c.** Make the percent of the bounty awarded proportional to the number of (upvotes minus downvotes).
   **d.** Deduct and discard a bounty if the (non)answer is deleted or voted lower than negative five, unless it was awarded by the person who offered it.

2.b. makes sense to me, because the non-answer (that triggered this post) somehow got two votes,  Apparently others agree (that it was a non-answer), since it was deleted not long after I posted this question.

Comment: The +25 wasnt someone else's bounty, it was half of your bounty.  It was award because you didn't award it and the answer was posted during your bounty and received enough upvotes to qualify for an automatic partial award.

Comment: And whether or not a question on which a bounty is offered gets answers that the person offering the bounty likes has no bearing on the reputation cost to the person offering the bounty. If you offer a 50 points bounty, it's gone, even if the question gets no answers at all.

Comment: I assume [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782645/250725) is the answer in question.  I'm not familiar with the topics, but how that answer managed 2 upvotes is beyond me.  The answer is virtually nothing and I agree that is was a non-answer.

Comment: You certainly could have downvoted the answer to keep it below the 2 threshold needed for automatic partial award

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes, and apparently someone agrees with you because the non-answer isn't there any more!

Comment: @mhelester: I probably did not have the ability to downvote back then.

Comment: Interesting that this is the third or fourth time that the A.I. to suggest duplicates did not suggest a question someone else later identified as a duplicate.  In one of those instances, the duplicate and my question had several shared words in their titles.  (And in another incident, the suggested duplicate was quite obviously not even close.)

Answer (score 2):

If you would link to the post in question, it would be mighty helpful. However, the [FAQ on this is pretty clear](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount

So, no one "awarded 25 to one of the non-answers" but it was given to the highest voted "answer" or "non-answer".

Sure, the rules on bounties aren't perfect but, as I've seen it put so well before, it's an advertisement and not a guarantee of an answer. If you paid for a billboard advertisement and didn't get any business from it would you ask for your money back?

Ah, [here it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226718/why-dont-so-have-a-feature-to-get-back-the-offered-bounty-to-a-question-if-the/226719#226719) from [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded?tab=answers&sort=newest) he put it pretty dang clear there.

### But

after just glancing at the post and the "answer", if you were to reword your question then you may have a possible feature request, though I'm not sure how it would work just yet. Because, whether or not you lose the rep is one thing, but someone gaining rep for not even coming close to answering just because they were the only person to answer is another.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why bounties are deducted at the time of offering is that people would get answers, but would not award bounty to save reputation.

As @codemagic said, you may start a feature request, but it is likely that it would be downvoted(i.e rejected)